# Trouble Looping through XML nodes

Tags: xml, loops, xslt

My xml

```
<INSPECTION_AREAS>

<AREA id="1" name="NorthWest Region">
<INSPECTION_SECTORS>
   <SECTOR id = "654" name = "Angola">
   </SECTOR>
   <SECTOR id = "852" name = "Lafouche">
       </SECTOR>
   <SECTOR id = "419" name = "Lake Borgne">
   </SECTOR>
</INSPECTION_SECTORS>
</AREA>

<AREA id="2" name="SouthWest Region"> 
<INSPECTION_SECTORS>
   <SECTOR id = "106" name = "Orleans">
   </SECTOR>
   <SECTOR id = "968" name = "Plaquemines">
       </SECTOR>
   <SECTOR id = "455" name = "Forty Arpent">
   </SECTOR>
</INSPECTION_SECTORS>
</AREA>

<AREA id="3" name="MidWest Region">
<INSPECTION_SECTORS>
   <SECTOR id = "698" name = "West End">
   </SECTOR>
   <SECTOR id = "232" name = "St. Bernard">
       </SECTOR>
   <SECTOR id = "768" name = "Grand Isle">
   </SECTOR>
</INSPECTION_SECTORS>
```

I am trying to list each sector for each area. When I try the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//INSPECTION_AREAS/AREA">
     ----<xsl:value-of select="@name"></xsl:value-of>----<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
```

I get just a list of my Areas

```
----NorthWest Region----
----SouthWest Region----
----MidWest Region----
```

Which is fine. When I attempt to list the sectors for each area, using the following code

```
<xsl:for-each select="//INSPECTION_AREAS/AREA">

     ----<xsl:value-of select="@name"></xsl:value-of>----<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:for-each select=".//INSPECTION_AREAS/AREA/INSPECTION_SECTORS/SECTOR">
          <xsl:value-of select="@id"></xsl:value-of><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:for-each>   

</xsl:for-each>
```

I get the different areas, but each area has the same list of sectors. I.e...

```
----NorthWest Region----
 Angola
 Lafouche
 Lake Borgne
----SouthWest Region----
 Angola
 Lafouche
 Lake Borgne
----MidWest Region----
 Angola
 Lafouche
 Lake Borgne
```

I'm not getting the distinct sectors for each distinct area. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. ANy help on this would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the inner loop, the "context" is already at the correct node `//INSPECTION_AREAS/AREA`.  Change the inner loop select criteria to a relative XPath:

```
select="INSPECTION_SECTORS/SECTOR"
```

However, I strongly suggest you read up on the difference between "pull" processing (which you are doing) and "push" processing, where you let the natural function of the XSLT engine do the iteration work for you.  Once you master the concepts it is usually much simpler to use.

Comment: OhEmGee...Thank you so much. I feel so slow now. But changing that worked like a charm